export a runnable jar file from eclipse using macOS
I am attempting to export a runnable jar file from eclipse in macOS. I get run the eclipse project and it works exactly how it is suppose too. Exported into a runnable jar is not working. I am getting this error . This is also my log file from terminal trying to boot from terminal
johnzalubski@Johns-MacBook-Pro desktop % java -jar ribe.jar                                                                                                             
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1023)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:529)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 14 more
johnzalubski@Johns-MacBook-Pro desktop % 

I tried the running from terminal.

Which version of Eclipse is it? Which version of Java are you targeting during development, and which one are you trying to run your jar file with? JavaFX became part of the standard runtime with 1.8, but was removed from Java 11 onwards.

"JavaFX became part of the standard runtime with 1.8, but was removed from Java 11 onwards" -- To be more accurate, JavaFX was never part of Java SE. Some vendors, such as Oracle, decided to include JavaFX in their JDKs/JREs. Oracle only did this for versions 8-10, and even then not for all operating systems. Other vendors, such as Azul Zulu and BellSoft Liberica, currently still provide JDKs/JREs that include JavaFX (if you pick the right package).

That said, your error is caused by JavaFX not being on the class-path/module-path when running your application.

afaik you can't do this unless you use jpackage but somebody will come along at some point with a definitive answer I guess

You have not provided any details or how the project is built. Are you building your project with a build tool like Maven or Gradle? Just an Eclipse project?

@aled I am just using a eclipse export don't know how to use the other 2.

Probably Eclipse doesn't know how to export the JavaFX pacakges. Try searching for how to use JavaFX with jpackage.

@Slaw so I don't need to install maven or create a maven project?

I didn't mention anything about Maven (or any other build tool). I was only adding information to another user's comment. Whether or not you use Maven (or another build tool) is up to you (though I do recommend using a build tool for non-trivial Java projects).

Yes. Plus mostly anything involving JavaFX is non-trivial owing to having to meet it's own dependencies as the basic first step

@g00se I don't know what you mean by non-trivial

JavaFX is complex and has a lot of moving parts to package before it all works correctly. It's essentially separate from 'normal Java'. So you need all the tool help you can get
